# "Датский" — с большой буквы?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Наткнулась на разные варианты написания слова "Датский". Как все-таки правильно? Интересует конкретно сочетание "принц Датский" (речь о женихе Русалочки у Андерсена).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что Вы имеете в виду: если титул, то *принц Датский*, если принц, живущий в Дании, то *принц датский*, а если  возлюбленный Русалочки у Андерсена, то там нет ни титула, ни указания, что это происходило в Дании.

Это сказка о жертвенной любви вообще, а не об отношениях Русалочки из Дании с принцем датским (она может быть из любого европейского государства, вот как в русских сказках "*В некотором царстве, в некотором государстве*" без привязки к какой-то стране), его Снежная королева - не датская, а финская. Сказка имеет мифологическую основу, и хотя автор в сказке отчасти размышляет о положении дел в своей стране, но смысл сводится к общечеловеческому. В образе Русалочки слились все европейские мифы, в том числе и русские, а принц - просто принц сказочной страны, без отношения к Дании.

Comment: Людмила, но ведь титулы пишутся с прописной только в официальных текстах.